# WKWebView XMLHttpRequest Failed to load resource

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, xmlhttprequest, wkwebview

everyone!

I have WKWebView which loads local XML with js inside.

```
function loadSegment(url,uuid) {
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onerror = () => rejected();
    xhr.onabort = () => rejected();
    xhr.ontimeout = () => rejected();
    xhr.onload = () => xhr.status === 200 ? handleSegment(url, uuid, xhr.response) : rejected();
    xhr.open("GET", url);
    xhr.responseType = "arraybuffer";
    xhr.send(null)
}

function handleSegment(url,uuid,res) {
// url, uuid, res to json
// webkit.messageHandlers.LoadHandler.postMessage(<#JSON#>)
}

function rejected() {

}
```

After WebView has been successfully loaded file I evaluate

```
webView.evaluateJavaScript(script, completionHandler: { (response, error) in
// Error handling
}
```

Script evaluates successfully. But in Safari Inspector I see following error

```
[Error] Failed to load resource: The network connection was lost. (05.ts, line 0)
[Error] Failed to load resource: A server with the specified hostname could not be found. (05.ts, line 0)
```

It tries to execute request the following url: http://edge.flowplayer.org/cilla_black_bean_sauce/1/216p-lo/00.ts

The most strange thing is what it works perfectly on simulator.

Have anyone faced similar problem?

Comment: It may be CORS. Is this called from "http://edge.flowplayer.org/" ???, if it is not, it is CORS. (Cross Origin Request)

Comment: Thank u for answering. Not  from "edge.flowplayer.org/". In case it is CORS what is the issue with real device?

Comment: Read this, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS You can find a solution

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and fixed it with a webview-configuration. Simply use the code below in your `viewDidLoad()` or similar (if you're using Swift):

```
webView.configuration.preferences.setValue(true, forKey: "allowFileAccessFromFileURLs")
```

Answer (score 0):

According @Dion answer, for Obj C

```
WKWebViewConfiguration *configuration = [[WKWebViewConfiguration alloc] init];
[configuration.preferences setValue:@true forKey:@"allowFileAccessFromFileURLs"];
self.wkWebView = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero configuration:configuration];
```